# Referencing a dynamic table in VBA in order to autofill a formula (r1c1/a1 style)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to achieve the following in VBA:

- Fill a column from 2nd row to LastRow with a vlookup with the mention that the range of the vlookup is **dynamic**.
- I used Match (see code snippet below) to identify the position of that column and also the last row.
- I thought about referencing it in FormulaR1C1 but I have no idea how to reference the range with these variables (esentially the **last line of code** in my snippet) in either .Formula or .FormulaR1C1

Snippet

```
LastRowBin = wsbin.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set wsbin = Inputwb.Worksheets("Raport_POS_BIN") 
colcopydoi = Application.Match(Search_doi, wsbin.Range("4:4"), 0)
newtgtlastrow = shttgt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

/ This would be a formula that works but that doesn't have a dynamic reference for the range.

```
With shttgt.Range("D2")
.Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Input!Z2:AA20500, 2, FALSE),0)"
.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & newtgtlastrow)
End With
```

/Range to use

```
wsbin.Range(wsbin.Cells(5, colcopydoi), wsbin.Cells(LastRowBin, colcopydoi))
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: `"You can concatenate strings  with a " & variable & " like this"` for you, use that Range's Address as your `variable`

Comment: Maybe try like this : `set rg = wsbin.Range(wsbin.Cells(5, colcopydoi), wsbin.Cells(LastRowBin, colcopydoi))` ---> check if the rg range is correct by activating the wsbin sheet then put temporary code `rg.select`. If the selected range is correct, then add `With shttgt.Range("D2:D" & newtgtlastrow) : .Value = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Raport_POS_BIN!" & rg.Address & ", 2, FALSE),0)" : End With` ---> this should fill sheet shttgt from D2 to whatever row with the lookup formula. Not tested in my side.

Comment: The thing that I'm curious, how your code works to have a value for `LastRowBin=` using `wsbin` while you set wsbin as a variable for Raport_POS_BIN sheet `Set wsbin = Inputwb.Worksheets("Raport_POS_BIN")` after that line ? Do you already have set the wsbin sheet before your `LastRowBin = ` line ?

Comment: @karma that worked, i adjusted that a bit and it worked wonders. Thanks a lot! Regarding your 2nd comment, it was just copy-paste of lines of codes so i think i messed up the order of these in here and not in my code.

Comment: @DanAndreiSica, thank you for your clarification. Glad that it finally work.